# Frames are not being updated from storyboard frames

Tags: ios, iphone, frame, cgrect

So I want to lay out a `UITableView` and I want the cells to calculate their own height. I can do this with `systemSizeFittingSize`, but this doesn't always return the correct height, as the rows still have their frame from the storyboard (or xib).

I want to update the frames so that they are what they will be on the device.

How can I do this? I have tried `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded`, but I would have to do this on the highest view in the hierarchy to achieve the desired effect, as each view seems to use the frame of their superview.

I am setting the `tableViewDataSource` and calling `reloadData` in `viewDidLoad` in my viewcontroller.

Is there a way to set the correct frames before `viewDidLoad` gets called?

Edit: I want to give the height of a subview to a layout object in my `viewDidLoad`, so that it can work its magic providing a nice layout. Now this object only does the layout calculations. I notice that the height I request (through `view.frame.size.height`) in `viewDidLoad` is the same as in my storyboard, again telling me that in `viewDidLoad` the frames haven't been updated yet... Anyone with a workaround?

Answer (score -1):

I think `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` may be something that you need:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

But setting the correct frames before `viewDidLoad` is possible only if you know the size before and then you can just calculate it in `init`.

Comment: That is where I return the height that I calculate by using a prototype cell, setting its data and then I ask it to layout itself so that I can get its height. The problem is here that the width of the cell is incorrect, and thus the height gets calculated incorrectly...

Comment: @vrwim Are you sure that it's a problem with cell's width and not table view's width?

Comment: I instantiate the cell from a xib, and it still has the frame from there. If I want to update the layout, it takes the one from the tableview, which is also incorrect

Comment: OK, but you mentioned that the problem is that the width of the cell is incorrect at the moment of calculating its height, if I understand  you correctly. And what I ask you now is whether you're sure that table view's width is correct?

Comment: I am sure it is incorrect, because in `viewDidLoad` my viewcontroller and everything in it still has the sizes from the storyboard, so I cannot use the frames to calculate my cell sizes.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to calculate cell frame in `viewDidLoad`? Can you confirm that cell width is still incorrect in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`?